# #flutter: A problem configuring ':cloud_firestore_web'

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

so when i try to add firebase to my project I start getting these errors and cant find any answered question on this.
please help out because this [Build Failing with an exception when adding firebase_auth or cloud_firestore in the pubspec.yaml file (firebase_core is working):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63595675/build-failing-with-an-exception-when-adding-firebase-auth-or-cloud-firestore-in) isn't working for me.

these are my dependencies in the pubspec.yaml

```
'''dependencies:
    flutter:
    sdk: flutter

     firebase_core: ^0.5.0
     firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
     cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
     firebase_analytics: ^6.0.0
     cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
     animated_text_kit: ^2.2.0
     google_fonts: 1.0.0'''
```

these are the dependencies in the app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.6.0'
```

}

and this is the error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * Where:
 Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 362

 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore_web'.
 > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type 
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log 
 output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 2s
 Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter upgrade`

In your build.gradle, remove everything else and this if your android project is using kotlin

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

If not using kotlin, only have the following as dependencies

```
dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

update `distributionURL` found in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle--all.zip
```

Run `flutter clean` after and you'll be good

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 362

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore_web'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: I updated my answer. look here for more details https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#a-android-installation